# I want to know why this joke is supposed to be hilarious

Tags: humor

> A couple is anxiously waiting to hear the results of a medical test for their unborn child.
> The doctor says: "I will start with the good news; Your child will always find a parking space."

It's just hard for me to catch it.
Thank you.

Comment: The joke is that the test shows that the child is disabled. It's in pretty poor taste, some may find it offensive, but even overlooking that it is certainly not hilarious.

Comment: @nnnnn Oh, now I understand. Thank you for your help. It was a quite offensive joke.

Comment: It’s not hilarious: it’s a sick joke.

Comment: @nealK I do hope you will not be offended if I flag this to the moderators for removal. I accept entirely that you did not grasp the meaning - but that now being clear I trust you will agree that it is not the sort of "joke" that should receive airtime on the site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about culture and (potentially poor taste) humour, not the English language as such.

Answer (score 2):

#### The doctor is saying that the test shows a disability.

In many countries, there are regulations about parking spaces that are reserved for individuals with disabilities; you will usually be able to spot them, because there will be a stick figure in a wheelchair painted on the ground on them. Since they're reserved for individuals with disabilities, they will frequently be unused even when the rest of the parking lot is full.

So, when the doctor is saying "The good news is that your child will always find a parking space," he's using black humor, by calling attention to the silver lining of your child being able to find parking spaces easily, instead of the fact that your child will be born disabled.